# How to implement a "switch" in a rule set?

Tags: rules

I would like to make a rule set that functions as a switch with breaks in PHP.  Example:

- Rule 1- User has role A, redirect to 1
- Rule 2- User has role B, redirect to 2
- Rule 3- User has role C, redirect to 3
- Rule 4- no conditions, redirect to 4

In other words:

- If a user has role A, redirect to 1.
- If a user has roles B and C, redirect to 2.
- If a user does not have roles A, B, or C, redirect to 4.

Is there an easy way to do this in Rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable called "done".

- First rule in the set checks for role A, sets done and redirects.
- Second rule in the set checks if done is true, and role is B, sets done and
  redirects.
- Third rule in the set checks if done is true, and role is
  C, sets done and redirects.
- Fourth rule checks if done is true,
  redirects.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this.  Side note: even for redirection, the done variable does not appear to be optional. With my current rule set, the user is always redirected to the page set in the final rule of the set, even if they meet the conditions for one of the earlier rules.  I know the earlier rules are being evaluated because adding a "Set message" action shows the message but the redirect is for the final page.

Comment: Works great-- for those unfamiliar with Rules, a tip- you can create a "truth value" variable, and then instead of checking whether it is set to true, just check "whether data value is empty".

Comment: Great, I've deleted the part about "done" being possibly optional for redirects, since it was untrue.